# Getting specs of my laptop in Greasemonkey (userscript)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

Is there a way to get information about my laptop in Greasemonkey (userscript)? I'm looking for information like, the Model of my MacBook, CPU, Memory, Uptime, Videocard, Display Resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some of these informations. I've listed them and added an example output

**GPU:** https://gist.github.com/cvan/042b2448fcecefafbb6a91469484cdf8

```
AMD Radeon Pro 560 OpenGL Engine
```

**Amount of cpu cores:** `navigator.hardwareConcurrency` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorConcurrentHardware/hardwareConcurrency)

```
8
```

**Screen resolution:**

- width: `window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio`
- height: `window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio`

**Memory/Timing**: `window.performance.memory` or `window.performance` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/performance)

```
MemoryInfo {
  totalJSHeapSize: 19300000,
  usedJSHeapSize: 16100000,
  jsHeapSizeLimit: 2190000000
}
```

**Device:** `navigator.userAgent` prints out some device information

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36*
```

---

**Interesting Library:** https://github.com/jackspirou/clientjs